# db.update not updating database

Tags: python, web.py

I am new to python and web programming. I am trying to sync database rows containing program state entries with program state stored in the disk. However in the database hpartDirs, the column IS_FULL_PROCESSED is not getting updated. I fired up the python interpreter, but don’t realize what i am doing wrong here. The function call checkIsHpartProcessed(indexFile) is working properly.

```
    import web 
    ..
    urls = ( 
    '/hpart/syncdb','hpartSyncDb'
    )
    db = web.database(dbn='mysql',\
                      user=<retracted>,\
                      pw=<retracted>,\
                      db='classifier',\
                      host='localhost')
    ..
    class hpartSyncDb:
            def GET(self):
                    hpartDirs = db.select('hpartDirs')
                    for hpart in hpartDirs:
                            indexFile=os.path.join(hpart.PATH,"index.hpart")
                            print "Updating "+indexFile+"with is hpart processed value"+str(temp) # Added just for debugging purposes
                            temp=checkIsHpartProcessed(indexFile)
                         db.update('hpartDirs',where='ID=$id',id=hpart.ID,IS_FULL_PROCESSED=temp)
                    raise web.seeother('/hpart/showdb')
```

Here is a sample output from the interpreter

```
    Updating /opt/bs/yourfile.html.hpart/index.hpartwith is hpart processed value1
    0.0 (7): UPDATE hpartDirs SET IS_FULL_PROCESSED = '1', id = 1L WHERE ID = <built-in function id>
    0L
    Updating /opt/bs/pr?sid=2oq.hpart/index.hpartwith is hpart processed value-1
    0.0 (8): UPDATE hpartDirs SET IS_FULL_PROCESSED = -1, id = 2L WHERE ID = <built-in function id>
```

What am i doing wrong here i dont understand, please help.

Comment: What is `$ID` function?

Comment: Are you saying that i am using db.update incorrectly ??

Comment: I dont know about `$ID` function. But, Do the queries update other fields properly?

Comment: I am trying to just update the IS_FULL_PROCESSED field only. That is what is not working

Comment: Okay. What does the `$ID` function do?

Comment: Its supposed to be place holder for dynamically selecting the ID attribute for each iteration of the loop (the docs [http://webpy.org/cookbook/update ] don’t exactly specify how this can be achieved)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variables directly via db.update.

You have to use `vars=` with either bringing your local variables with `vars=locals()` and use $variable in your update-query or specify a dictionary `vars={'id': 1, 'foo': 'bar'}` as suggested below.

```
 class hpartSyncDb:
            def GET(self):
                    hpartDirs = db.select('hpartDirs')
                    for hpart in hpartDirs:
                        indexFile=os.path.join(hpart.PATH,"index.hpart")
                        print "Updating "+indexFile+"with is hpart processed value"+str(temp)
                        temp=checkIsHpartProcessed(indexFile)
                        myvar={'id': hpart.id, 'isprocessed': temp} 
                        db.update('hpartDirs',where="ID=$id", IS_FULL_PROCESSED=$temp, vars=myvar)
                    raise web.seeother('/hpart/showdb')
```

I left out updating ID as it seems the id should not be changed during update.